# How to identify which button is clicked in flutter

Tags: button, dart, flutter, identify

I have 4 buttons showing a different list each time a button is clicked . How to identify which button is clicked using flutter ?

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign a callback that calls a different method for each button

```
new FlatButton(
  child: new Text(confirmText),
  onPressed: () => onOkPressed(),
),
```

or you can pass a parameter

```
new FlatButton(
  child: new Text(confirmText),
  onPressed: () => onButtonPressed('okButton'),
),
```

Comment: What about providing more information about what you try to accomplish before asking for better answers?

Comment: Ex. If I have added button via for loop the how can I Identify which button is tap? any tag option is that ?

Comment: You can use the `for(var x, ...` variable in `onPressed: () => ...`

Comment: Please check [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956591/4930378](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55956591/4930378). The answer explains how you can assign ids to multiple buttons using custom button class and identify them.

Comment: @Pro looks like overkill to me.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The solution you provided didn't work me for multiple dynamic FloatingActionButtons.

Comment: You answer should work fine for static buttons and thank you for providing that but if you're creating a list of buttons dynamically on each button actions, the button id (dynamic value based on the action) for all the buttons always appeared to be the last button id when using your answer.

Comment: I think I understand your use case now.