# How to know which button is tapped in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I came across this question : [How to identify which button is clicked in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588528/how-to-identify-which-button-is-clicked-in-flutter)

But Is there any better way to detect which button is tapped?
Ex.
I created 100 button via for loop then how to know? In iOS we are using **tag** property so If there is this kind of option then it will really handy to detect.

**EDITED:**

Below are my code

```
List<Widget> pageCurrentPageIndicator(int currentIndex, int totoalCount) {
    List<Widget> tempWidget = new List<Widget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < totoalCount; i++) {
      Container container = Container(
        width: 47.0,
        height: 30.0,
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Image.asset(
            (i == currentIndex
                ? 'lib/assets/radioBtnActive.png'
                : 'lib/assets/radioBtn.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.contain), onPressed: () {
              whichButtonistaped(i);              
            },
          )
      );
      tempWidget.add(container);
    }
    return tempWidget;
  }

  void whichButtonistaped(int btnTag){
    print(btnTag);
    setState(() {
        currentBannerIndex = btnTag;               
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign to each button a different callback

```
void onPress(int id) {
  print('pressed $id');
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      RaisedButton(onPressed: () => onPress(0),),
      RaisedButton(onPressed: () => onPress(1),),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Pls check my updated. I know this way but any other way is available ?

Comment: No, that's the only way.

Comment: Why doesn't this work when the 0 and 1 comes from the index in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many solutions available for this and the ones that are available are for static buttons which didn't work for me. Here's what i did for multiple dynamic FloatingActionButtons in my project that worked,

**Custom button class which assigns dynamic id to each button:**

```
class FAB extends StatelessWidget {
  final int id;
  final Function(int) onPressed;
  final String buttonText;

  const FAB({this.id, this.onPressed, this.buttonText});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {onPressed(this.id);},
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        child: new Text(this.buttonText,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0))
    );
  }
}
```

**Create button using the class above:**

```
new FAB(
  id: id,
  onPressed: buttonFunction,
  buttonText: 'Button Text'
)
```

**Button function:**

```
buttonFunction(id) {
  print('Button id: $id');
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54728693/4930378

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `key` property of the widget.

Here is a solution:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Row(
    children: [
      TagButton(onPressed: (k) => onPress(k)),
      TagButton(onPressed: (k) => onPress(k)),
    ],
  );
}

void onPress(Key id) {
  print('pressed $id');
}
```

With the following custom Widget:

```
typedef TagButtonPressedCallBack = void Function(Key key);

class TagButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final TagButtonPressedCallBack onPressed;

  agButton({
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: UniqueKey());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
      if (onPressed != null) onPressed(key);
    });
  }
}
```

output:

```
I/flutter ( 6371): pressed [#2ca50]
I/flutter ( 6371): pressed [#2180d]
I/flutter ( 6371): pressed [#2ca50]
```

That solution gives you the unique identifier of the `TagButton` widget.

---

If you want the id of the `RaisedButton` inside the `TagButton`, you can generate a `Key` in the `build` method and pass it to the `RaisedButton` like so :

```
typedef TagButtonPressedCallBack = void Function(Key key);

class TagButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final TagButtonPressedCallBack onPressed;

  TagButton({
    Key key,
    this.onPressed,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var k = UniqueKey();
    return RaisedButton(
        key: k,
        onPressed: () {
          if (onPressed != null) onPressed(k);
        });
  }
}
```