# How to pass a key to a function?

Tags: flutter, function, dart, collections

I have several buttons, images to which I pass through the Map collection. When clicking on the button, I would like to receive the transmitted image key and write it to a variable.

I do not know how to correctly get the key from the button when you click on it, could you tell me? `icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[1].toString())),`

My function:

```
_clikFunction (){
   int keyNumber;
  keyNumber = imagesIcon[value];
  }
```

My collection:

```
  final imagesIcon  = <int, String>{
    1: IconImages.test1,
    2: IconImages.test2,
    3: IconImages.test3,
  };
```

My button:

```
Column(         
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[1].toString())),
                                            onPressed: _clikFunction,
                                            ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(  
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[2].toString())),
                                            onPressed: _clikFunction,),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[3].toString())),
                                            onPressed: _clikFunction,), 
                      ),          
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: Have you tried assigning each button a different callback, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53152937/10019278

Answer (score 0):

```
Column(         
     children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[1].toString())),
                                            onPressed: _clikFunction(1),
                                            ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(  
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[2].toString())),
                                            onPressed: _clikFunction(2),),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[3].toString())),
                                            onPressed: _clikFunction(3),), 
                      ),          
                    ],
                  ),








_clikFunction (int key){

  imagesIcon[] = key;
  }
```

Comment: This passes the key from all the buttons, but I can't even press them

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired result in this way

```
_clikFunction (int key){
 int keyNumber;
  keyNumber = key;

 print(keyNumber);
}


Column(         
     children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[1].toString())),
                                            onPressed: () =>_keyFunction(1)),,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(  
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[2].toString())),
                                            () =>_keyFunction(2)),

                      SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                                            icon:  Image(image: AssetImage(imagesIcon[3].toString())),
                                           () =>_keyFunction(3)),
                    ],
                  ),
```